# Reading data from SQL image field

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, dynamics-ax-2009, axapta

In AX 2009, I need to query and report from the SYSDATABASELOG table's DATA field (type IMAGE) in an SSRS report.  However, it appears to be stored as raw data, and I need to be be able to read/interpret this field.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue before, also using SSRS reports.

What you should do is to convert the SSRS image source from Embedded to DB.

your initial data should look like this:

[image]

open the SSRS and create an Image.
 In the Image properties you need to change the selected Image source to `Database`:
[image]

Under use this field put the relevant field from your query.

and under MIME type select the image format:

[image]

That It!

**Note:**

During my small research I ran in to [**this**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) MSDN requesting to avoid using IMAGE types because it will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server.

Be advise!

[image]

Comment: Thank you Gil for your reply.  Unfortunately, the data in the image field is not an 'image' file, it is actual data stored by Dynamics AX.